# End a sleep loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I've written a python script that contains a sleep loop to watch a log file, waiting for a new line to handle:

```
file = open('logFile.log', 'r')
while 1:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        print line, # already has newline
```

I'd like to modify this so whenever it takes more than 1 hour without new lines, end the loop and continue the script. So far didn't succeed in doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important point to this issue is that there is no new line for 1 hour **CONTINUOUSLY**, so it's really necessary to reset the time counter after a new line prints.

```
count = 0
one_hour = 60 * 60
file = open('logFile.log', 'r')
while 1:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        count = count + 1
        if count >= one_hour:
          break
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        print line
        count = 0   # Here needs to reset the time couter!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a counter:

```
count = 0
file = open('logFile.log', 'r')
while 1:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        count = count + 1
        if count >= 3600:
          break
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        print line, # already has newline
        count = 0
# if you get here an hour without any newlines has passed
```

Comment: it better if you move condition `count >= 3600` from `if` loop to `while` loop i.e. `while count!=3600`.  correct?

Comment: For clarity it might be better. In any case I would use an inequality - `while count < 3600:`. Also - I just added a `count = 0` after the print statement to reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `while 1` (which, btw, should really be written as `while True`) to a condition that checks how long time has been spent in the loop.

Something like:

```
file = ...
now = time.time()

while time.time() - now < 1 * 60 * 60:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of Code.

```
file = open('logFile.log', 'r')

while True:
    timeWait = 60*60 # Change the Value to something less to check whether the code works properly or not.
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        timeWait = timeWait - 1
        file.seek(where)
        if timeWait == 0:
            break
    else:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `while` to check for 1 hour slot and reset the `startTime` as below:

```
file = open('logFile.log', 'r')
startTime = time.time()
while (time.time()-startTime) >= 3600:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        startTime = time.time() #record the last time output was available
        print line, # already has newline
```