# How to keep continuously write to Oracle table even if table is not accessible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert multiple records into the one Oracle table continuously. For which I have written below python script.

```
import cx_Oracle
import config

connection = None
try:
    # Make a connection
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config.dsn,
        encoding=config.encoding)

    # show the version of the Oracle Database
    print(connection.version)

    # Insert 20000 records
    for i in range(1, 20001):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT into SCHEMA.ABC (EVENT_ID, EVENT_TIME) VALUES( "+ str(i)+" , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        connection.commit()
except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
```

So, During the insert, when I change the table name it just create an exception and comes out of script(as the table is not available and cannot write). What I want is, Even if when I do the rename and table is not available, the script needs to keep continuously trying insert. Is there a way this can be possible?

Comment: Do not commit inside the loop : this will lock database and modification from elsewhere will be suspended. Commit once you have finished loop

Comment: If I do that, It won't replicate the current production scenario where commit is happening after each and every statement

Comment: The main problem is the script stops when the table is not available. I want the script to keep retrying until the table gets available

Comment: Add a while (data not inserted) loop around database execution . Put this one in a try except pattern . The try for executing database stuff and exit of while loop. The except part does a sleep.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example please?

Comment: See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835674/end-a-sleep-loop-in-python) for examples of a "sleep loop" to keep retrying an action.

Comment: I expect the solution would want to be checking connection validity, and closing/reopening connection if needed.  A pool (with max=1) can be useful, since the pool has some internal checks and internal reconnection logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what Ptit Xav was talking about. I added some code to quit after a max number of retries, since that's often desirable.

```
# Insert 20000 records
for i in range(1, 20001):
    retry_count = 0
    data_inserted = False
    while not data_inserted:
        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT into SCHEMA.ABC (EVENT_ID, EVENT_TIME) VALUES( "+ str(i)+" , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            connection.commit()
            data_inserted = True
        except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
            print(error)
            time.sleep(5) # wait for 5 seconds between retries
            retry_count += 1
            if retry_count > 100:
               print(f"Retry count exceeded on record {i}, quitting")
               break
    else:
        # continue to next record if the data was inserted
        continue
    # retry count was exceeded; break the for loop.
    break
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150107/3061852) for more explanation of the `while... else` logic.

Comment: Instead of using "+" string concatenation you should use bind variables for security.  And since the statement is re-executed you also need bind variables for performance & scalability.  This problem was noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to encapsule the insert logik in a *function* that catches the possible exception and performs the retry

```
def safe_insert(con, i):
    """
    insert a row with retry after exception
    """
    retry_cnt = 0
    sql_text = "insert into ABC(EVENT_ID, EVENT_TIME) VALUES(:EVENT_ID,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) "
    while True:
        try:
            with con.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(sql_text, [i])
                con.commit()
                return
        except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
            print(f'error on inserting row {i}')
            print(error)
            time.sleep(1)
            retry_cnt += 1
            if (retry_cnt > 10):
                raise error
```

Similar to @kfinity's answer I also added a *limit on retry* - if this limit is exceeded the function raise an exception.

Note also that the function uses *bind variables* in the `INSERT` statement which is preferable to the concatenation of the *values* in the statement.

The usage is as simple as

```
for i in range(1, 20001): 
    safe_insert(con, i)
```

Comment: The poster's definition of 'table is not available and cannot write' isn't clear, but perhaps the solution could use [`connection.callTimeout`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.call_timeout).  And/or the sqlnet.ora file could have settings like `RECV_TIMEOUT`, see  the cx_Oracle manual [Network Configuration](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html#network-configuration).

Comment: A side comment: since the example commits for each INSERT, it would be more efficient to turn on [autocommit](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/txn_management.html#autocommitting).  This will halve the number of 'round-trips' between Python and Oracle DB.

Comment: Interesting comments thanks @ChristopherJones. *can't write*: I guess the OP impelements some DIY *rolling logging* with *rename table* plus *create new table* and wan't loose rows at the time the table doesn't exists (so timeout will not help). *Autocommit*: could be also good idea for this toy example.